# What is the effect of the underscore in [A-Z] [_a-zA-Z0-9]*?

Tags: bash, terminal, grep, regular-expression

In regards to regular-expressions what is the effect of the underscore in

```
[A-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

Comment: It's an underscore, in the same way that the "`a`" is an "a".

Answer (score 4):

This means capture an underscore. Examples of matches include:

```
A
A_
AAA
A_123
A_abc
```

Use a site such as https://regex101.com/ to test your regular expressions and get an explanation on what each part means.